# Is there a way to restrict access to certain applications by specific users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I have create several applications that communicate with our central auth server via doorkeeper. I want to make some applications accessible/inaccessible for specific users.

Is there a way to restrict access to specific oauth_applications and return a 401?

Comment: Doorkeeper is used for **Authorization** -- if the server returns a 401 status, it means "I don't know who you are".

Comment: Other libraries, such as `pundit`, are for **Authentication** -- if a server returns **403** status, it means "I know who you are, but you're not allowed to do this".

Comment: Doorkeeper is for **Authentication** (who are you) and pundit for **Authorization** (what are you allowed to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to achieve this would be the following:

1. In your doorkeeper application, change the Users table to include a permissions relationship. Something like, User -> has many -> permissions

And those permissions could contain just the name of the application you want to give them access to, (Or the ID of the application, you choose)

2. Then, in your config/initializer/doorkeeper.rb - inside Doorkeeper::JWT.configure - you add which applications that particular user can access inside the token payload, something like:

```rb
token_payload do |opts|
  ...
  token[:permissions] = user.permissions.pluck(:application_name)
end
```

If you are using Doorkeeper without JWT, you can still pass extra information to the token by prepending a custom response to the ResponseToken object like so:

```rb
Doorkeeper::OAuth::TokenResponse.send :prepend, CustomTokenResponse
```

and CustomTokenResponse just need to implement the methods `body`, like so:

```rb
module CustomTokenResponse
  def body
    additional_data = {
      'username' => env[:clearance].current_user.username,
      'userid' => @token.resource_owner_id # you have an access to the @token object
      # any other data
    }

    # call original `#body` method and merge its result with the additional data hash
    super.merge(additional_data)
  end
end
```

extra information can be found in Doorkeepers' wiki: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Customizing-Token-Response
and in the Doorkeeper JWT gem: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-jwt#usage

Answer (score 3):

On 9 Feb 2020 a new [configuration option](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/commit/5795bc26627d3899ae813ecb5fa64289f5345e45) was introduced in Doorkeeper to exactly do this.

Therefore, you can configure `config/initializer/doorkeeper.rb`:

```
authorize_resource_owner_for_client do |client, resource_owner|
  resource_owner.admin? || client.owners_whitelist.include?(resource_owner)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted the same behaviour. I use the `resource_owner_authenticator` block in `config/initializer/doorkeeper.rb`. When a user has one or more groups which are connected with an Oauth application it can continue.

```sh
rails g model UserGroup user:references group:references
rails g model GroupApplications group:references oauth_application:references
```

```rb
    resource_owner_authenticator do
      app = OauthApplication.find_by(uid: request.query_parameters['client_id'])

      user_id = session["warden.user.user.key"][0][0] rescue nil
      user = User.find_by_id(user_id)

      if !app && user
        user
      elsif app && user
        if !(user.groups & app.groups).empty?
          user
        else
          redirect_to main_app.root_url, notice: "You are not authorized to access this application."
        end
      else
        begin
          session['user_return_to'] = request.url
          redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
        end
      end
    end
```